# export list for modules in scheme

Tags: module, scheme

Is there a way to define a module in Scheme, and specify that all the bindings are to be exported, without listing each and every one of them explicitly?

Is there a way to do the above while specifying a list of binding that are not to be to be exported?

Comment: I use Chez Scheme, so whatever solution needs to be compatible with Chez. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Scheme reports before R6RS does not have libraries defined in the spec so no. It is not possible in an portable way. However most implementation of R5RS actually have their own module system. eg. Racket has powerful syntax to do exatly as you want:

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-from-out <module>))
(provide (except-out (all-from-out <module>) lambda))
```

From R6RS we have libraries, however their export spec needs every export by name.

## [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-10.html):

```
#!r6rs
(library <library name>
  (export <export spec> ...)
  (import <import spec> ...)
  <library body>)
```

## R7RS:

```
#!r7rs
(define-library <library name>
  <library spec>)
```

The R7RS changed the syntax with purpose but has the same ability. See the R7RS-small report ([pdf](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs.pdf), page 28)